# API Monday x Power BI - Get all data of the boards

Tags: powerbi, monday.com

I want to directly link my Monday boards to Power BI for live data.

- Need to directly connect multiple boards at the same time to Power BI
- Get all the information from each boards
- History date stamp of when the stage/task changes

The current query I’m using to fetch data from just one frame is this one, how can I modify it to fetch from all available frames?

```
letSource = Web.Contents(“https://api.monday.com/” & “v2”,[Headers=[#“Method”=“POST”,#“Content-Type”=“application/json”,#“Authorization”=“Bearer ####”],Content=Text.ToBinary(“{”“query”“: “”{ boards (ids: ####) { items { id name column_values { title text } } } }”“}”)]),#“JSON” = Json.Document(Source,65001),data = JSON[data],boards = data[boards],boards1 = boards{0},items = boards1[items],#“Converted to Table” = Table.FromList(items, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),#“Expanded Column1” = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#“Converted to Table”, “Column1”, {“name”, “column_values”}, {“Column1.name”, “Column1.column_values”}),#“Expanded Column1.column_values” = Table.ExpandListColumn(#“Expanded Column1”, “Column1.column_values”),#“Expanded Column1.column_values1” = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#“Expanded Column1.column_values”, “Column1.column_values”, {“title”, “text”}, {“Column1.column_values.title”, “Column1.column_values.text”}),#“Changed Type” = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#“Expanded Column1.column_values1”,{{“Column1.column_values.title”, type text}}),#“Pivoted Column” = Table.Pivot(#“Changed Type”, List.Distinct(#“Changed Type”[Column1.column_values.title]), “Column1.column_values.title”, “Column1.column_values.text”),#“Renamed Columns” = Table.RenameColumns(#“Pivoted Column”,{{“Column1.name”, “Name”}})in#“Renamed Columns”
```

Need to directly connect multiple boards at the same time to Power BI.
Get all the information from each boards.